# Aptitude Installing a lot of Packages?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I recently launched `aptitude` only to notice that it wanted to install 2GB of packages "`to satisfy dependencies`". Is is normal for aptitude to want to install this many packages all at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on what Ubuntu flavour you are currently using and what you were trying to install at the time...  If it was a KDE application then it will pull in all the KDE libraries so that program will work, although 2gb is a lot for one program...